# Open PDF with Flex Mobile Project

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, mobile, pdf-reader, flexpaper

I want to be able to read PDFs inside a Flex Mobile Project (I'm working with Flash Builder 4.6 and Android and iPad).

I've tried successfully stagewebview to load a pdf from a web server with this:

```
webView = new StageWebView();

            webView.loadURL("http://<url>/Paper.pdf");

            webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 100,this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight);
            webView.stage = this.stage;
```

But what I really want it's something more visual. I mean, where you can create a flip book, go to page X, or similar. Something like this:
http://devaldi.com/zine/NZ_Tourism_2007.php?ro=flash,html

I've already tried FlexPaper, but Zine doesn't work on Flex Mobile Project.

Do you know if there is something to do this? or how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used FlexPaper but instead of include the component inside a Flex Mobile Project, I've used their documents publisher and I load an url in my application.

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've found this Ane:
https://github.com/memeller/vfrReaderNativeExtension

It only works for iOS and isn't very "visual", but it's something.